# "Close tabs" conversastion very slow without alert sound and another sound issue

Tags: 18.04, gnome, sound, configuration, bug-reporting

On my recent-reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 I've noticed some annoying issue with firefox when I tried to close it, these symptoms are:

1. If I click close firefox only with one tab, it closes immediately
2. If I click close firefox with two tab, it tags around 3 seconds to pop out the "close tabs?" conversation, also the alert sound (percussion) doesn't play entirely, you can only hear the last closing sound (the last microseconds of this percussion sound, you know what I mean...), if I cancel this and re-click the close button, the conversation pops out immediately with clear sound.
3. The more tabs I open on firefox, the slower the conversation pops out.
4. Other sound issue:
   4.1: When I change the volume, you should hear the "water-drop-like"sound, for me I don't hear it when I press volume +/- eventhough the volume pops out immediately, however after around 3 seconds the sound comes back (but normally the sound control icon already disappears for the previous one and re-appears with normal sound). But if I open music or youtube, the sound doesn't lag in starting to play.
   4.2: In the empty Terminal when you try to press delete button, the another type of alert sound (I call it heavy drum pad sound) also delays in coming, also sometimes the Terminal lags, which never happened before.

So what do these share in common? Seems like the configuration of the gnome is wrong which makes the notification lag, since my knowledge is very limited I don't know what can I do...

PS: I have 3 ubuntu machines and since last time my electricity was gone and destroyed my home directory on my ubuntu, I cleared all the disk and reinstalled this, so I've been using ubuntu 18.04 for a long time and this is the first time I notice such problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling two times and the problem is still there, and after so many configuration tries and I realized that this is the problem:
The day before this problem came out, I just sold my speaker (a professional one), it was connected to my motherboard's speaker output, after the selling, since my display supports sound output through HDMI, so I decided using this as my speaker, and this is where the problem comes out, I think there is some compatibility with the HDMI sound output which makes a lag when the system needs to pop out a notification with sound.